# Can i use ARKit with imported video stream and sensor data in iOS 11

Tags: arkit

The ARKit is pretty awesome. However, it looks like only support iPhone camera. Is it possible to use external data source (Stream video and attitude sensor) in the ARKit?

Comment: Any leads on this ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sensor data is collected by the [`ARSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) class:

> An ARSession object coordinates the major processes that ARKit performs on your behalf to create an augmented reality experience. These processes include reading data from the device's motion sensing hardware, controlling the device's built-in camera, and performing image analysis on captured camera images. The session synthesizes all of these results to establish a correspondence between the real-world space the device inhabits and a virtual space where you model AR content.

We don't have any insight in how this class handles the data or any possibility to configure the session besides the [`ARConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration).